# How to retrieve value from C++ matrix in Swift?

Tags: c++, ios, swift, opencv

I have a C++ function what returns a `cv::Mat` value

```
+(cv::Mat *) makeGray:(UIImage *) image {
    // Transform UIImage to cv::Mat
    cv::Mat imageMat;
    UIImageToMat(image, imageMat);

    //Transform image to grayscale
    cv::Mat grayMat;
    cv::cvtColor(imageMat, grayMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    return grayMat;
}
```

I call that function in Swift using:

```
let grayMat = OpenCVWrapper.makeGray(photoImageView.image)
```

I know Swift doesn't import `cv::Mat`, what's the best alternative so that I get that array in one piece?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.. Just convert the `cv::Mat` to a `malloc`'d byte array and return that.

```
+ (uint8_t *)makeGray:(UIImage *)image count:(uint32_t *)count {
    // Transform UIImage to cv::Mat
    cv::Mat imageMat;
    UIImageToMat(image, imageMat);

    //Transform image to grayscale
    cv::Mat grayMat;
    cv::cvtColor(imageMat, grayMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    int size = grayMat.total() * grayMat.elemSize();
    void *bytes = malloc(size);
    memcpy(bytes, grayMat.data, size);
    *count = size;
    return bytes;
}
```

Then on the swift side it should be an `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>` with a count and you can free it by calling deallocate or convert it to an array of bytes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, when I run the function I get this error: `Cannot initialize return object of type 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *') with an lvalue of type 'void *'` looks like c++ thinks `bytes` is void even though when I print to st:cout I get the value : `std::cout << bytes << std::endl; 0x12827a000`

Comment: @Cristian;  do:  `static_cast<uint8_t*>(malloc(size))`.. It's because C++ doesn't implicitly convert the return value of malloc..

Comment: Thank you that worked great! I apologize for my ignorance, how do I go about deallocating `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>` so far I have `let random : UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> = OpenCVWrapper.makeGray(photoImageView.image)`

Comment: @Cristian; Call `random.deallocate` to deallocate it.. you might have to call `deinitialize` first though.